# Javascript usage, are these good comments or are they overkill?

Tags: javascript, function, comments

I wish to add helpful comments without being too verbose. Before answering imagine given Javascript functions buried somewhere inside hundreds or thousands of lines source code. Also notice that in the comments I gave function parameters a little bit more meaning by better describing their usage instead of using actual names of parameters. I do this to better guide the user (programmer) who may at a later date need to refactor or modify the script.

```
    var ctx = getCanvas();// getCanvas(width, height)
    grid(ctx);// grid(context, element size, line width, line color)

    function getCanvas(width = 200, height = 150) {
        // code to run
    }

    function grid(ctx, elSize = 10, width = .3, color = 'green') {
        // code to run
    }
```

Comment: best comments are good functions names. Read `Clean Code` book, there is the answer for your question

Comment: This is an absolutely opinion-based question, and as such it is off-topic here.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would put the comments at the point at which the function is called- why not put full comments describing the function and its parameters above the functions themselves?

Comment: I assume most of the listed arguments are default arguments? Just reading your comments leaves me a bit confused about that. A good IDE might show you the list of arguments and allow you to peek at or jump to a function declaration immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's always good to have your code properly commented.

Add a standard/descriptive comments before the start of the function instead of lines of comments.

There are many ways to add a comments in JavaScript; here is my recommendation / best practices.

Using `//` is better than `/* */` because then you can use the latter to take out an entire block containing other comments. However, if you want to use an automatic documentation generation tool, you must use comments similar to JavaDoc style.

This is an example that would work with YUI DOC (best one) http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yuidoc/#start

```
/**
* This is a description
* @namespace My.Namespace
* @method myMethodName
* @param {String} str - some string
* @param {Object} obj - some object
* @param {requestCallback} callback - The callback that handles the response.
* @return {bool} some bool
*/
    function SampleFunction (str, obj, callback) {
         var isTrue = callback(str, obj); // do some process and returns true/false.
         return isTrue ;
    }
```

Other params examples: http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126310/does-javascript-have-a-standard-for-commenting-functions/39391392#39391392

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to use **[JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/)** for better readabilty

```
/**
 * describe your function
 * @param {number} width - describe your parameter
 * @param {number} height - describe your parameter
 * @return {type} describe your returned value/object
 */
function getCanvas(width = 200, height = 150) {
    // code to run
}
```

this also comes in handy with your IDE

Answer (score 1):

Comments are good pratics of programing, so its, in my opinion, let the code more clean. For instance, when your code need maintenance, the other programmer will understand. I thing that you need comment just what do you think necessary to other understand and try to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult question as it's down to your own preference, you also have to consider other developers having to read your code in the future.

I personally get a little "comment fatigued" with some approaches, but others would say you can't comment enough. I think a good naming convention for functions and variables can often remove the need for a large majority of comments.